# help in solving $z^2+|z|^2=1+2i$

Tags: complex-numbers

I can't solve this:
$$z^2+|z|^2=1+2i$$
I've found $\sqrt{ \frac{2}{5}}$ for the modulus of z but I can't explicit about the angle of z . 
The result of the book is, $ \pm (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i*\sqrt{2})$ but there are so many mistakes that I'm afraid is not very reliable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z= a+bi$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $|z|^2 =z\cdot \overline{z}$ we have $z\cdot 2a = 1+2i$ so $$ z={1\over 2a}+{1\over a}i$$
thus $a={1\over 2a}$ so $a=\pm {\sqrt{2}\over 2} $. So $z=...$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you put $z=a + \mathrm i b$ and put it carefully in your equation, then you just have to compare the real and imaginary part of the right hand and left hand side. Just try it.

Answer (score 1):

$$z^2+|z|^2=(a+bi)^2+a^2+b^2=a^2+2abi-b^2+a^2+b^2=2a^2+2abi$$
So $$2a^2+2abi=1+2i$$
Equating real and imaginary parts:
$$\Re:2a^2=1\Rightarrow a=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\Im:2(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})bi=2i\Rightarrow\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}b=1\Rightarrow b=\pm\sqrt{2}$$
Thus,$z=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pm\sqrt{2}i$